# Exporting SQL Query Results to Text File From Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: mysql, t-sql, command-prompt, visual-studio-2017, export-to-csv

I've looked for the past hour online to find an answer specific to my situation, but none have solved my question. I am trying to query a MySQL database (which I have done successfully) and then output the results to a text file.

I have read that using bcp and "queryout" are the best methods of achieving this goal. My code is below, but it continues to give me the following errors: "Incorrect Syntax Near 'L'.".

How do I fix this? Is there an easier way to export my results from Visual Studio to a text file?

```
set @logtext =
'"
SELECT category, occurTime, sourceKeyName, recipe, "value", formulaName, startTime, endTime , BatchID 


FROM dbo.Batch
LEFT JOIN dbo.BatchHeader ON Batch.uniqueBatchID = BatchHeader.uniqueBatchID
LEFT JOIN dbo.RecipeHeader ON BatchHeader.uniqueBatchID = RecipeHeader.uniqueBatchID
LEFT JOIN dbo.BReportEvent ON RecipeHeader.uniqueBatchID = BReportEvent.uniqueBatchID
LEFT JOIN dbo.RecipeFormula ON BReportEvent.uniqueBatchID = RecipeFormula.uniqueBatchID

WHERE category = 'L-FAIL-MSG'

AND occurTime  >= DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())
AND "value" != ' '
"'  

DECLARE @logtext varchar(1000)
DECLARE @cmd varchar(2000)

SET @cmd = 'bcp ' + @logtext + ' queryout "C:\Users\anduaguibe\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\HelloWorld\HelloWorld\upstreamData.txt" -U uID -P uPass -c'

EXEC master...XP_CMDSHELL @cmd
```

Comment: The error says it.  Incorrect near L.  Suggest you make it two single quotes around L-FAIL-MSG  so ''L-FAIL-MSG''  (these are not double quotes, they are 2 single quotes).  Looks like their may well be other issues in there too though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bcp has always worked for me when pushing result sets out to a file, so that's good, as far as I can see.

The bigger problem here is how you're formatting the `@logtext` query string; You need to escape out the single quote by adding a second one before it. Here are a couple of problem spots for you:

```
WHERE category = 'L-FAIL-MSG'
```

and

```
AND ''value'' != ' '
```

In the first instance, you're giving it a string and then a literal and then another string, without any formatting.
You need to either add that second quote to escape it and treat `L-FAIL-MSG` as a string literal, or make `L-FAIL-MESSAGE` a variable push that into the string.

The second instance will give you an issue, because you've again not escaped the quote- it appears to be a string followed by another string without any operators to concatenate them or anything.

Here's how it might need to be formatted

```
WHERE category = ''L-FAIL-MSG''
```

and

```
AND ''value'' != '' ''
```